# how to get the linq list having Ids from IEnumerable<Object>

Tags: linq, ienumerable

The code below `userModel.Carriers` is the type of `IEnumerable<CarrierModel>`.
`userModel.Carriers` has a list of carriers having Ids. With those Ids, I want to get CarrierDivision usign linq. But, I can't get it right because `linq sqlexpression is not compatible with IEnumerable expression`.

```
userModel.Carriers = carriersForRegion.Select(carrier => Mapper.Map<CarrierModel>(carrier))
                    .ToList();

var carrierDivision = from c in db.CarrierDivision where c.Contains();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection.Contains` will generate `.. WHERE CarrierId IN (1, 2, 3)` sql query

```c
var carrierIds = userModel.Carriers.Select(carrier => carrier.Id).ToArray();

var divisions = db.CarrierDivision
    .Where(division => carrierIds.Contains(division.CarrierId))
    .ToArray();
```

In case `db.CarrierDivision` returns `IEnumerable`(not database), then I would suggest to create `HashSet` of carrier ids.

```c
var carrierIds = userModel.Carriers.Select(carrier => carrier.Id).ToHashSet();

var divisions = db.CarrierDivision
    .Where(division => carrierIds.Contains(division.CarrierId))
    .ToArray();
```

With `HashSet` search executed without extra enumerations - O(1)